# How to add .xml file to .dll project in Code::Blocks editor

Tags: c++, xml, dll

I have written a small c++ program to read the content of a .XML file.
It works as a console application. But when I compile the project as a .dll it gives no error but ignores the .XML Content.

My question is how to include the .XML file into my .dll

I am using the Code::Blocks IDE. I set the checkmark with options->compile when right-clicking on the .XML file, but this doesn't help. I also tried to include the .XML in my code with

```
#include <data.xml>
```

but now I get error Messages. Please help.

---

I have found a workaround for my problem:

I define the content of my .XML file as a string xml_message and then use

```
#include "data.xml"

xml_document doc;
doc.loadSring(xml_message.c_str())
```

instead of

```
xml_document doc;
doc.loadFile("data.xml");
```

Comment: The .xml file is an external file, it will not be embedded into the .dll - and you can't include an xml file

Comment: Thx. Do you know how to access the .XML data by the .dll? I have put the .XML and .dll into the same folder. Or do you know about an alternative? I have used pugixml and it works when I start a console application with the same code as the .dll.